# help with weight painting

Tags: weight-painting

This model is very picky about when I try to weight paint it, anyone have any tips?[image]

Comment: Hello, you don't give enough details, what's the problem exactly? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Does the model have enough geometry? The blend file would be helpful as stated above

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh is very low poly and probably has few vertices. But Weight painting relies on vertices with more of them meaning more control. You can add a *Subdivision* modifier to your model, set to "Simple" (which will keep the overall shape of your model) with a subdivision count that suits your needs. If you leave it at "Catmull-Clark", it will round out your mesh.

[image]